# How can I recursively list Md5sum of all the files in a directory and its subdirectories?

Tags: command-line, md5sum

I want to list (and save) Md5 check sum of all the files in a directory and  save that list in a text file called `md5sum.txt`

it would be also nice if I could

- Integrate it within `tree` command (which creates a tree structure of folders and files)
- Make it work on Folders and Sub folders (this is sort of important)

Comment: For separate checksum files for each subfolder, see also [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71286224/111036)

Answer (score 61, accepted):

You could use `find` (in the directory)

```
find -type f -exec md5sum '{}' \; > md5sum.txt
```

If you want to exclude the `md5sum.txt` file itself, you can do so:

```
find -type f \( -not -name "md5sum.txt" \) -exec md5sum '{}' \; > md5sum.txt
```

You can also use a loop: turn on recursive globbing

```
shopt -s globstar
```

Then, in the directory:

```
for i in **; do [[ -f "$i" ]] && md5sum "$i" >> md5sum.txt; done
```

You can exclude the file itself from this one as well:

```
for i in **; do 
  [[ -f "$i" ]] && 
  [[ md5sum.txt != "$i" ]] && 
  md5sum "$i" >> md5sum.txt
done
```

Neither of these produces a `tree`-like structure. But they do print the relative path to the file from the starting directory. If you want the absolute path, use `find /path/to/directory ...`

You might want to turn off globstar afterwards (`shopt -u globstar`)

Comment: this also creates md5sum of the `md5sum.txt` file itself. would be nice it wasn't

Comment: @Anwar see edit for slightly cumbersome exclusion ^_^

Comment: Ah! seen it. I better one line in a huge md5sum.txt then extra 5 lines of code. Anyway, thank

Comment: can always do:  "> ../md5sum.txt" to ensure that the file doesn't get included in the result

Comment: For binary files don't forget to add -b after the md5sum command.

Comment: if you wanna continuously filenames in output, do `sort -k2 -o md5sum.txt md5sum.txt`

Answer (score 2):

You can execute the following command:

```
md5sum /path/to/directory/* > /path_to_result/md5sum.txt
```

The output in the result file will be something like that:

```
46684e3891d990acde2e723ee3d4e94a  /var/log/alternatives.log
39cf1ebf93452ed5f8b240b35ae73f9f  /var/log/alternatives.log.1
aa6c09c411d1d0870bca5f401d589332  /var/log/alternatives.log.2.gz
```

Comment: Doesn't work if there is a directory. Says `md5sum: /path_to_dir: Is a directory`

Comment: @Anwar running `md5sum /path_to_dir/*` will execute `md5sum` on every file in the directory

Comment: What about the other files inside subdirectories?

Comment: @Anwar - it won't work on sub-directories (which was defined as *nice to have* in the question)

Comment: but I see this added to the edition, **this is sort of important**

Comment: This doesn't answer the question at all.

Comment: this is all wrong.